# Let $\Sigma \subseteq 2^X$ consisting of sets S for which either S or $S^c$ is finite. For which $X$ is $\Sigma$ a $\sigma$-algebra?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\Sigma$ be the family of subsets of $X$ consisting of sets $S$ for which either $S$ is finite or $S^c$ is finite. For which $X$ is $\Sigma$ a $\sigma$-algebra? Give and prove a complete characterization of all such $X$.

I am confused as to how to prove this, surely this would require an infinite number of finite subsets otherwise say if $X=(-\inf,\inf)$ and $S_1={1}$ and $S_{2}=2$ then $S_1\cup S_2$ is not an element of $\Sigma$? Alternatively if each $\Sigma$ has the elements $X,\emptyset, S, S^c$ then this is a $\sigma$ algebra for $X=\mathbb{N},\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{R}$

Comment: It seems to me if $X=\mathbb Z$ then the subsets $A_i=\{2i\}$, $i\in\mathbb Z$ are in $\sum$ but their union is not.  Therefore $X$ is not a $\sigma$-algebra.  Can't you play the same trick with any infinite set?

Comment: Unless I didn't understand correctly, I think in your example $S_1\cup S_2$ has just two elements, so it is still in $\sum$.

Comment: In the example, $S_1 \cup S_2 = \{1,2\}$ which is not in $\Sigma$

Comment: $\{1,2\}$ is a finite set and therefore it is in $\sum$.  Or have I totally misunderstood the question?

Comment: Oh my mistake it does make sense. So if the union of all S covers X then it forms a sigma algebra. So therefore X must be a finite subset of any of the X's I defined above?

Comment: $\cup S$ over all $S\in\sum$ is always equal to $X$ since $S$ contains all the sets consisting of single elements.  The points is, I think, that if a set is infinite then there are (countable) subsets that are not finite and their complement is also not finite.  Therefore such sets are not in $\sum$.  Since they are countable then they can be obtained as a (countable) union of singletons.  There's the contradiction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $X$ is infinite, let $x_i$ be distinct elements of $X$ for $i\in\mathbb N$.  Then each $\{x_i\}$ is in $\sum$.  But $A=\cup_i \{x_{2i}\}$ is an infinite set with infinite complement, therefore $A\not\in\sigma$.  Therefore $\sum$ is not closed under countable union.

Therefore the only sets $X$ that satisfy the condition are finite sets.

Answer (score 0):

You must check that X belongs to sigma, this implies that X must be finite,
the complementary part is trivial, then for the countable union take the union of U_n, this union must be contained in X which verify the condition.
Otherwise if X it is not finite then its cardinality must be greater or equal than aleph0, then it can be decomposed in two complementar sets with the same cardinality which not verify the condition.

Comment: $X^c=\emptyset$ which is a finite set, therefore $X$ is always in $\sum$ no?

Comment: I thought that. Surely checking X isn't the problem? Surely I just need to take a finite subset of any of the X's I defined above and I will obtain a set which is a $\sigma$ algebra?

Comment: No, because $\sigma$-algebras are closed under countable union.  So if it contains infinitely many sets of size one, it must contain sets of size infinity.  Therefore the set of finite subsets will not be closed under countable union if $X$ is infinite.